# Copy paste a fixed row based on some condition else skip to next column in that row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Have data set in I11:X11 and I want to copy formulas seating I12:I12 into I13:X20 based on data contained in I11:X11.

Starting with I11, if that contains certain value lets say TEST, then want to increment row for that range to next column that is J11 and if J11 <> TEST, then copy  J12:X12 to J13:X20.

Further want to skip pasting this entire logic based on flag seating in column H13:H20, for example if H13  = Y, then skip to next row.

Adding a screenshot to further explaining the issue.
Condition should start with first member in range I11:X11, if it encounters first member <> TEST till T11 , then it should start copying from that range. In this case it encountered first <> TEST member at L11, then it should copy from L12:T12 to L13:T24 and V12:X12 to V13:X13. Further this logic should work on the flag contained in column H. If this column H Contains Y,then above logic should not paste in that row, this pasting activity should go on until last value in column H starting from H13.
The condition value from I11:T11 can change between TEST and any other values, not further.

Want to achieve this on a button click using a VBA code.

Adding Code, but it limits to the fixed column H values and Fixed row values.

```
Sub CopyOnCondition1()

     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range

     Set sh1 = Worksheets("SheetNameHere") 'change the sheetname

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("I11:T11")

        If Not cel.Value = "TEST" Then

            sh1.Range(Cells(12, cel.Column), Cells(12, 20)).Copy
            sh1.Range(Cells(13, cel.Column), Cells(24, 20)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

        End If

     Next

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("H13:H24")

        If cel.Value = "Y" Then sh1.Range("I" & cel.row & ":T" & cel.row).ClearContents

     Next
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAaqo.png)

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: I Mikku, actually I am new to excel VBA and dont have much idea about the syntax.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is not a free coding site. We can help you to solve the problem given that you have tried it yourself first. I will suggest you to google and learn about the syntax, then try and write a code yourself. If it still doesn't work, you can ask a question. We would be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for revert, even I would have preferred that but due to time constraint and critical delivery I have to post it here. I have pasted whatever I have started with. Thanks once again.

Comment: udpated with further changes

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand from the Question I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Sub CopyOnCondition1()

     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, c As Range

     Set sh1 = Worksheets("SheetNameHere") 'change the sheetname

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("I11:T11")

        If Not cel.Value = "TEST" Then

            sh1.Range(Cells(12, cel.Column), Cells(12, 20)).Copy
            sh1.Range(Cells(13, cel.Column), Cells(24, 20)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

        End If

     Next

     For Each cel In sh1.Range("H13:H24")

        If cel.Value = "Y" Then sh1.Range("I" & cel.row & ":T" & cel.row).ClearContents

     Next


End Sub
```

First It will paste in the complete Range. Then it wo go and check if `H` have `Y`, if yes, then it will delete the formula from that row.

Comment: Added image explaining the issue. Comments below to further explain the issue : Condition should start with first member in range I11:T11, if it encounters first member <> TEST , then it should start copying from that range. In this case it encountered first <> TEST member at L11, then it should copy from L12:T12   to L13:T24
Further this logic should work on the flag contained in column H. If this column H Contains Y,then above logic should not paste in that row

Comment: @Mikku..its partially working. Pasting in first row only but it goes until AB13. I guess first loop should be for H column and we should skip pasting if H column contains Y.

Comment: @NJB , There was some mixup in the cell number. I have amended it now.

Comment: @Mikku..its working thanks. Well initially I explained the issue keeping problem statement short. Further to extend this solution is to copy paste this entire solution  based on flag in column H till last value in H column. Values in column H will be dynamic, they will start for sure from H13.

Comment: Thanks for the help..I even don't know how to upvote the answer...creating another question will need all the efforts we have already done over here...I am happy to do that..but it won't make more sense as the issue is related the existing solution.

Comment: @ Mikku : Another thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372747/copy-paste-row-range-based-on-specific-condition-in-rowfixed-but-includes-blan